# converting first file to another file

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm new at programming and i  need help with converting first file to another file. The task is:

> Write a program that asks the user for two filenames. The first one should mark any existing text file. The second filename may be new, so the file with this name may not exist.
>
> The program's task is to take the first file of the file, convert it to capital letters, and write another file.

So far I have:

```
file_old  = input("Which file do you want to take ? ")
file_new = input("In which file do you want to put the content? ")

file1 = open(file_old, encoding="UTF-8")
file2 = open(file_new, "w")

for rida in file1:
    file2.write(rida.upper())

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

[image: The error pic]

Comment: The title is confusing.  Do you mean `file` instead of `fail`?

Comment: fail is Estonian for file

Comment: What is wrong with what you already have? How does it not work?

Comment: Any errors? what is the undesired behavior?

Comment: yea i mean file. There is something with this codefail1 = open(failold, encoding="UTF-8")

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the error :)

Comment: After your edit: Does the original file exist?

Comment: It doesn´t see old.txt, have you checked if it exists?

Comment: @Antimony i have a text file, where is a text. You mean that.

Comment: You should check where the file is located then. Python may not be looking in the right for the first file.

Comment: I have old.txt file in same folder as this programming code

Comment: Can you try putting in `C:\Users\Geddi\Downloads\old.txt` instead of just `old.txt`, as Ahmed suggested?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the full path to your file for your code to work.

I tested it and it works perfectly.

The input path should be like

```
C:\Users\yourUserName\PycharmProjects\test_folder\test_small_letters.txt
```

This should be instead of `old.txt` that you enter

for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" C:/Users/userName/PycharmProjects/pythonSnakegame/test_file_capitalize.py
which file you want to take ? C:\Users\userName\PycharmProjects\test_folder\test_small_letters.txt
In which file you want to put the content? C:\Users\userName\PycharmProjects\test_folder\test_big_letters.txt
C:\Users\userName\PycharmProjects\test_folder\test_small_letters.txt
C:\Users\userName\PycharmProjects\test_folder\test_big_letters.txt

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The new file was created and capitalized.

Comment: New users (<15 rep) can't vote. Additionally, asking for it is poor form. Your answer, however, looks fine.

Comment: @TemporalWolf , thanks for the advice , just saving myself from some harsh negatives I got for some questions earlier that might block me from asking ... , I noticed she is new so I wanted to indicate this upvote thing to her and whoever find the answer helpful

Comment: @Kertrudm you are most welcome ^_^ welcome to programming :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a more pythonic way, with the `with` statement. This creates a context manager which takes care to `close()` the file when you are done with it.

```
file_old  = input("Which file do you want to take ? ")
file_new = input("In which file do you want to put the content? ")
with open(file_old, 'r') as f1:
    with open(file_new, 'w') as f2:
        for line in f1:
            f2.write(line)
```